# Float div with child div

Tags: css

I know this is a strange question

what I want:  CODE 1

```
<a>
   <span class="a" style="float:left">boks 1 </span>
   <span class="b" style="float:left">boks 2 </span>
</a>
```

what my real code looks like: CODE 2

```
<a>
  <span class="a" style="float:left">boks 1 
     <span class="b" style="float:left">boks 2 </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Is there a way to get code example 2 to look like code example 1?  Is there a way to get a child span do float up onto the parent span?

EXAMPLE
http://jsfiddle.net/NCXGx/33/

Comment: Can't you just remove `float: left` from the inner `span`? If that doesn't work, then there must be more to this. Please create a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Hi Plexus81, Please remove the float from inner/child span where class="b". You will get the exact output you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the work for me.

```
<a style="display:;">
    <span class="a" style="float:left;display:inline-block;min-width:100%">boks 1 </span>
    <span class="b" style="float:leftdisplay:inline;">boks 2 </span>
</a>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCXGx/12/)